# How do I call a non-static method (that uses a WebControl) with a static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following snippet of code. I can only access the `PbcTreeView` in a non-static method, so I call it during Page_Load. However, the setTreeView() method can't access the object `b` not can it call the buildTreeView() method. (setTreeView() has to be static according to the WebMethod rules and buildTreeView can't be static because it uses the TreeView). How could I get it to do something similar to `b.buildTreeView()` that I have in the method?

Thanks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuildPbcTree b = new BuildPbcTree(PbcTreeView);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void setTreeView()
    {
        b.buildTreeView(); //how do I do this??
    }

    public class BuildTree
    {
        TreeView Tree;
        public BuildTree(TreeView t)
        {
            Tree = t;
        }
        public void buildTreeView() {...//implementation}
    }
```

Comment: You can't do that.  The whole point of AJAX methods is that there is no page lifecycle.

Comment: @SLaks thanks, what would you suggest as a work-around for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You must wrap BuildPbcTree in a Singleton class http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton

Comment: You have session object to your rescue. Store the data object in a non-static method (page_load) and then access the object from the session in the static method (`setTreeView()`)

Comment: @Slaks: can't or shouldn't?

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Can't.  This is totally impossible; the things he wants to work with do not exist at all.

Comment: @DennisR: That won't help; he wants to modify the rendered control on his page.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance of the class to the Static method. For example, in your Page_Load:

```
SetTreeView(b);
```

This assumes you change your web method to accept a BuildTree class.

Comment: That won't help; he wants to modify the rendered control on his page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `PbcTreeView` is some control on your page.

In that case, you are out of luck. You cannot modify server-side controls during AJAX calls (web methods). AJAX calls are designed to be used as follows:

1. You call your web method in JavaScript code.
2. The web method performs some database lookup or computation and returns the result.
3. **Your JavaScript code** updates the user interface.

You are trying to update the user interface *inside* a web method. That won't work. If you need to do that, use a postback or an asynchronous postback with an UpdatePanel.